# carrierwave image gallery is requiring a manual page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, carrierwave, unicorn

I have image gallery based on `carrierwave`, and I have rotate functions, it's working but I need to manually refresh the page if I want to see the changed(rotated) image.

I think I should tell the server that the file has changed, but I don't know how to do it.

I have `nginx` + `unicorn` as a server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like [ajax periodical updater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater) to control if image was updated or some similar technology. Basically it's simplier to ask server if something was changed periodically rather than force server to tell your application that he got something changed.